# Rename Displayed Field Name in Grails Domain Class

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

Given the following Grails Domain Classes, how do I go about renaming the displayed field name for isbn to be "ISBN" (as opposed to the default "Isbn") and authors to be "Author(s)" (as opposed to the default "Authors")?

```
class Book {
    String name
    String isbn
    static hasMany = [ authors: Author ]
}

class Author {
    String name
}
```

Comment: You can change the label of the property in messages.property !

Comment: @doelleri: Yes, we're using the default scaffolding that comes with Grails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use messages.properties file for that.
Go to grails-app --> i18n --> messages.properties

and define message like:

```
'<full packagePath>.<domain name>.<propertyName>.<attribute>' = <message>
```

book.isbn.label = ISBN

Comment: Thanks that worked! I did have to pay special attention to the case of the package path, domain class name, etc (camelCase) in case that helps anyone else.

Comment: yeah you need to pay attention for package hierarchy and class name and other things also..